# Swift Collectionview didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView with custom cell (xib file), I manage to display the collectionview but I don't manage to detect when I tap on a cell with the function :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
```

Usually, I manage to do that, but this time I don't know why it doesn't work. Actually I'm using this pods "https://cocoapods.org/pods/SACollectionViewVerticalScalingFlowLayout"

My code is :

```
class ProjectsController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewGridFormat: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionViewGridFormat.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "ProjectsGridFormatCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellProjectGrid")

...


    }
}

extension ProjectsController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : ProjectsGridFormatCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellProjectGrid", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProjectsGridFormatCell

        cell.lblProjectName.text = "Test project"

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        print("aa")
    }
}
```

But when I tap on a cell, "print("aa")" is not displayed.

Have I given enough information ? :)

Thanks for your help !! :D

Regards,

Comment: Did you set your view controller as a delegate of the collection view? You need to set both - delegate and datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Is "User Interaction Enabled" checked under the Identity Inspector in Storyboard?

Comment: I have added "self.userInteractionEnabled = true" in my UICollectionViewCell, and in Inspector, all the elements have it enabled. But it still doesn't work